# ¿Se puede aplicar un pipe a un valor de un form hecho con formbuilder desde un archivo ts? ( Uso angular )

Tags: angular, typescript, formularios, text, pipe

les comento, mi problema es que necesito hacer que el valor de un input sea editado tal que el valor inicial sea "nombre apellido" y el final sea "Nombre Apellido", y se me ocurrió encararlo por el lado de los pipes pero no logro dar con la forma ( ya probe con css antes y no me funcionó ).

El siguiente es mi formbuilder:

```
this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.currentuser.ClienteNombre, Validators.required],
      phone: [this.currentuser.ClienteTelefono, Validators.required],
      email: [this.currentuser.ClienteMail, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      address: [this.currentuser.ClienteDireccion, Validators.required],
      nombreEmpresa: [this.currentuser.NombreEmpresa],// Validators.required],
      rut: [this.currentuser.ClienteRut],// Validators.required],
      billingAddress: [this.currentuser.BillingAdress],// Validators.required,
    });
```

Si saben de alguna función que ya venga con angular para este tipo de cosas o algo comentenlo por favor, sería de gran ayuda.
Desde ya gracias por el tiempo que se tomaron en leer mi pregunta.
Saludos.

Comment: Puedes obtener los valores del formGroup, editarlos y volverlos a setear en el formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo agregando el pipe a `app.module` o el modulo que estes usando (shared, pipes, etc).

```
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "./profile-editor/profile-editor.component";

// ESTA IMPORTACIÓN ES IMPORTANTE
import { TitleCasePipe } from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ProfileEditorComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  // LO AGREGAMOS EN EL PROVIDER. 
  providers: [TitleCasePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Te suscribes a los cambios de tu form control e inyectas el pipe en el constructor:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let firstName = this.profileForm.get("firstName");
    firstName.valueChanges.subscribe(valor => {
      this.profileForm.patchValue(
        {
          // Actualizamos solo la propiedad que nos interesa. 
          firstName: this.titleCase.transform(valor)
        },
        // Esta linea es importante para que no de un error de
        // exceed call stack size.
        { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false }
      );
    });
  }
```

Ejemplo funcional [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/title-case-reactive-forms?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Editando..